# Freed up URL not available

Tags: facebook, username, facebook-username

We are opening a business (named after our road) and have created a new Facebook page.  We wanted a specific URL that was used by another person on the road.  They agreed to change their URL to free it up for us.  They have not deleted their page, just changed their URL.  Now when we try to use it, we still get a message that it is unavailable.

How long before the URL is free again?

Comment: Have you tried [contacting Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/360358877344441?rdrhc)?